# Should you use HTML in an image's alt attribute?

Tags: html, alt

Should you write :

`<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="large cat & dog">`

or

`<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="large cat &amp; dog">`

Comment: I'd go with the second one as ampersands are special characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for when you should use the entity for an ampersand instead of a single raw `&` character are the same for the value of an attribute as they are for anywhere else in HTML.

- You may always use the entity.
- You must use the entity if the character is followed by a word character (which a space is not).

Comment: What happens if a word character follows the entity?

Comment: @j08691 — Nothing special. OTOH, if a word character follows an ampersand then  it will either because an entity or will be an ambiguous ampersand, which are forbidden in many places.

Comment: @j08691: This -- https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-ambiguous-ampersand

Comment: @Abhitalks — "This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes."

Comment: Oops @Quentin. I was searching for reference on character references remembering having read this somewhere but found this and didn't look at the note!! But, it still holds, isn't it?